# What does the o modifier for a regexp mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

Ruby regexp has some options (e.g. `i`, `x`, `m`, `o`). `i` means ignore case, for instance.

What does the `o` option mean? In `ri Regexp`, it says `o` means to perform `#{}` interpolation only once. But when I do this:

```
a = 'one'  
b = /#{a}/  
a = 'two'
```

`b` does not change (it stays `/one/`). What am I missing?

Comment: You are not using the `o` flag in your regexp. Why are you expecting any effect of it?

Comment: Well, if using `o` flag means turn on the effect, then i though the `#{}` in a regexp may execute everytime  without the flag

Comment: Beware that in the Perl (as opposed to Ruby) docs http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html it is stated of the `o` modifier: "pretend to optimize your code, but actually introduce bugs". So in Perl, the `o` flag seems to have a different meaning to that of Ruby, and furthermore the Perl flag may be broken.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Straight from [the go-to source for regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html):

> `/o` causes any `#{...}` substitutions in a particular regex literal to be performed just once, the first time it is evaluated. Otherwise, the substitutions will be performed every time the literal generates a Regexp object.

I could also turn up [this usage example](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ruby/patternmatching.html):

```
# avoid interpolating patterns like this if the pattern
# isn't going to change:
pattern = ARGV.shift
ARGF.each do |line|
    print line if line =~ /#{pattern}/
end

# the above creates a new regex each iteration. Instead,
# use the /o modifier so the regex is compiled only once

pattern = ARGV.shift
ARGF.each do |line|
    print line if line =~ /#{pattern}/o
end
```

So I guess this is rather a thing for the compiler, for a **single** line that is executed multiple times.

Comment: Just a second ago I read a wiki about `Evaluation strategy`, I finally understand a lot. In ruby, assignment do the eager evaluation, so after the segment `b = /#{a}/`, `b` be assigned to `/one/`, that's to say, 'there is nothing business with the `o` flag'

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Modifiers".

Comment: a simple way to see what happens is this `pattern = 'a'; 10.times.map { (/#{pattern}/o).object_id }` vs `pattern = 'a'; 10.times.map { (/#{pattern}/).object_id }`, you can see how a new object gets instantiated every time vs the same object being reused.